# Image loading icon for flash/flex?

Tags: apache-flex, flash, loading

You often see those little 'petal' animations while an image or .swf file is loading in a Flash / Flex application.

Do I have to steal this from someone or is there a standard one available from somewhere. i would think there is somethin standard because everyones looks the same!

Ideally I want a flex Image control that displays such an icon when it is loading for more than 1/4 second.

Answer (score 3):

You can download that and other icons (as animated gifs) at [AjaxLoad](http://www.ajaxload.info).

Comment: thanks, but this is for animated gifs which dont seem to work in Flash. cool site tho

Comment: Flash CS3 will import an animated .gif as frames.  Do that and save it out as a SWF.

Answer (score 2):

Use the aforementioned [AjaxLoad.info](http://www.ajaxload.info/) and load the animated GIF into Flash CS3.  Save as SWF.

Answer (score 1):

Here are [a few "loading" SWF files](http://www.designswan.com/archives/18-flash-loading-animations.html) you can use.